# Count blank fields in entire Column

Tags: excel

I want to count all the blank fields in column B where column A contains values. I cannot find an appropriate method of doing this in Excel 2010.

I am also counting other values in column B, for example `=COUNTIF(B:B,"AST005")`.

Now I need to count the values in column B where column A has a value. If I use `=COUNTBLANK(B:B)` it returns 67500 where in reality it should return 15. How do I alter my formula?

Comment: `COUNTIF(B1:B1000, "")`?

Comment: Are what you think are blank cells really blank?

Comment: Use =COUNTBLANK(B:B) with a delimited range: =COUNTBLANK(B1:B50) for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your quextion right, you want to count rows where Column A is not blank AND Column B is blank?

For example

```
    A    B  
1   a    q
2   s
3   d    e
4        r
```

would return `1`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A<>"")*(B:B=""))
```

Comment: @chris_neilsen `SUMPRODUCT` doesn't usually require "array entry" - it doesn't here

Answer (score 2):

in Excel 2007+ there is `=COUNTIFS(A:A; "<>"; B:B; "")` - but i'm not sure about the second condition (don't have excel on this computer)

otherwise i suggest add this formula to a next column: `=IF(AND(A1<>"";B1="");1;0)` and sum the results :))

or you can use an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) `=COUNT(IF((A:A<>"")*(B:B="");1))` - you have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter it correctly *(but i recomment $A$2:$A$9999 instead of A:A)*...

Comment: COUNTIFS version looks good to me @deathApril +1.....but you can't use AND in an array formula like that, would have to be something like `=COUNT(IF((A:A<>"")*(B:B="");1))`

Comment: If using 2007+ `COUNTIFS` is the way to go.  But because of the reference to 67000 odd rows I'm guessing OP's using 2003